# Can we set access token to not expire?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

We are using Identity Server4, the default time is access token expire is 3600 seconds. Can we set it to not expire?

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
         {
         new Client
        {
        ClientId = "client",

        // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

        // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

        // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
            AccessTokenLifetime=3600
    }
};
```

Comment: why dont you set it to a very high value ?

Comment: Why would want to do this? Creating a very long lived Access tokens can be a serious problem if the token got compromised. It also prevents claims to be updated. If you want to extend the lifetime use Refresh Tokens.

Comment: actually we have a register endpoint, access token that does not expire and then we can revoke this from the backend if required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking AccessTokenLifetime is declared as an int so you could do

```
AccessTokenLifetime = Int32.MaxValue;
```

But that's really not going to be a good idea.  Once the access token is created its going to continue to work I dont think you expiring it in the backed is going to work as you would like.

For the fun of it

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Int32.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(t.Days);
```

results in a very ugly 24855 days or 68 years.

Comment: You can't use Int.MaxValue - because epoch time is used for the exp claim. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Nice one I should have dug deeper into the code.    I was thinking it would be better as a Uint16 but I guess this takes care of that.

Comment: In the identityserver4 I did not have this problem it generated the expiration date as 3710553928, it should convert to long internally

Comment: Correcting, you really have the problem, when we will authenticate the token on the client it gives the int32 overflow